# Caret won't install/load properly

Tags: r

when i do

```
install.packages(“caret”)
```

it appears that the package is successfully installed (R response is posted at the bottom of this text). However, when I run library(caret), I get the following error messages:

```
library(caret)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
there is no package called ‘lava’
```

Comment: Have you tried checking on 'lava'...?

Comment: What is that..?